# Prob. 20, Chap. 4 in Baby Rudin: Distance from a point to a non-empty set in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, continuity

Here's Prob. 20, Chap. 4 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $E$ is a nonempty subset of a metric space $X$, define the distance from $x \in X$ to $E$ by $$ \rho_E (x) = \inf_{z \in E} d(x, z). $$
>
> (a) Prove that $\rho_E (x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \overline{E}$.
>
> (b) Prove that $\rho_E$ is a uniformly continuous function on $X$, by showing that 
>   $$ \left\vert \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \right\vert \leq d(x, y) $$ 
>   for all $x \in X$, $y \in X$.
>
> *Hint:* $\rho_E(x) \leq d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$, so that $$\rho_E(x) \leq d(x, y) + \rho_E(y).$$

My effort:

Part (a):

> Suppose $\rho_E(x) = 0$. Let $\delta$ be any positive real number. Then as $$\rho_E(x) = \inf \left\{ \ d(x, z) \ \colon \ z \in E \ \right\},$$ 
>   so there is a point $z_\delta \in E$ such that $$0 \leq d\left( x, z_\delta \right) < \delta. $$ Thus, every $\delta$-neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$. So either $x \in E$ or $x$ is a limit point of $E$. Hence $x \in \overline{E}$.
>
> Conversely, suppose that $x \in \overline{E}$. Then either $x \in E$ or $x$ is a limit point of $E$. So, for every real number $\delta > 0$, there is a point $z_\delta \in E$ --- and this $z_\delta$ may very well be $x$ itself --- such that $$d\left( x, z_\delta \right) < \delta.$$
>   So no positive real number $\delta$ can be the infimum of the nonempty, bounded from below subset $$ \left\{ \ d(x, p) \ \colon \ p \in E \ \right\}$$ of $\mathbb{R}$, which implies that 
>   $$\inf \left\{ \ d(x, p) \ \colon \ p \in E \ \right\} = 0;$$
>   that is, $$\rho_E(x) = 0.$$

Part (b):

> Let $x, y \in X$. Then, for any point $z \in E$, we see that 
>   $$ d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z).$$ 
>   So we must have 
>   $$\rho_E(x) = \inf \left\{ \ d(x, z) \ \colon \ z \in E \ \right\} \leq \inf \left\{ \ d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ \colon \ z \in E \ \right\} = d(x, y) +  \inf \left\{ \ d(y, z) \ \colon \ z \in E \ \right\} = d(x, y) + \rho_E(y).$$ 
>   And therefore, 
>   $$ \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \leq d(x, y). \ \tag{1} $$
>   In (1), we interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$ to obtain 
>   $$ \rho_E(y) - \rho_E(x) \leq d(y, x) = d(x, y). \ \tag{2} $$
>   From (1) and (2), we can conclude that 
>   $$ \left\vert \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \right\vert \leq d(x,y) \ \mbox{ for all } x, y \in X. \ \tag{3}$$
>   Now, given a real number $\varepsilon > 0$, let us choose a real number $\delta$ such that $$0 < \delta \leq \varepsilon. \ \tag{4}$$
>   Then, for any points $x, y \in X$ for which $d(x, y) < \delta$, we see that 
>   $$  \left\vert \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \right\vert \leq d(x, y) < \delta \leq \varepsilon,$$ 
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \left\vert \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \right\vert < \varepsilon,$$
>   showing that the function $\rho_E \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

Are my proofs correct? If so, is my presentation good enough too?